# Rails (3) validation of non-ActiveRecord field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model with a corresponding form, for which I use ActiveRecord validations. At the bottom of the form I'd like to have a single confirmation checkbox which should not be persisted, but which must be checked for the form to be submitted. I'd also like any errors that stems from this checkbox not being checked to display alongside the ActiveRecord errors.

Now I could cobble something together in the controller manually, but I'm wondering if there is a built-in, cleaner way to handle this kind of situation?

Comment: Did you try this http://www.perfectline.ee/blog/building-ruby-on-rails-3-custom-validators ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should add this in your model:

```
validates_acceptance_of :check_me
attr_accessor :check_me
attr_accessible :check_me # if you already have attr_accessible defined in your model
```

and this in your view:

```
<%= form_for @your_model do |f| %>
  # some code
  <%= f.check_box :check_me %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: if the db column doesn't exist there's no need to add the `attr_accessible`

Comment: it is necessary if you already have attr_accessible in your model :) but I edit my answer to make it clear. Thank you paozac